# Angular directive can't get the child elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

First, the directive selector-child is in the div element in the property.

```
 <div id="ed" selector-child>  // selector-child attrs directive
    <div class="testClass">Im no any directive</div>
    <div class="listClass" ng-repeat="aa in aas">Im has ng-repeate directive{{aa.text}}</div>      
 </div>
```

Then, the **aas model data is also defined** in the controller.

Finally, **want to through the class name to search with ng-repeate directive of the elements in this list.** 
 The results showed that is empty,but no directive class name can be found, why? to solve???

```
myApp.directive('selectorChild', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope,element,attr) {
         console.log(element.find('.testClass'));
          // can be found -> ouput [div.testClass]
         console.log(element.find('.listClass'));
          // no found -> ouput is empty[]
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `$timeout` to allow the `ng-repeat` to be generated in the dom

```
myApp.directive('selectorChild', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope,element,attr) {
         $timeout(function(){
            console.log(element.find('.listClass'));
         });
        }
    };
});
```

As an alternative you could add another directive to the repeating elements that `require` this directive, then use `$last` property of `ng-repeat` child scope to do whatever it is you plan to do

Comment: Thanks~  I get to the elements of success.，but why use $timeout??

Comment: because your directive will fire before `ng-repeat` has had a chance to run and create the list of elements

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `querySelector` method of JQlite:

```
 console.log(element[0].querySelector('.listClass'));
```

Comment: if the first one works why would OP need to change query method?

Comment: I tried it ,  console.log output  is null ,  results is null~ why?